# Lubuntu update stuck

Tags: lubuntu, update-manager

At startup I get a window ([see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCP0j.png)) which tells me to install updates. If I click on "Install now" it gets stuck. If I install updates with apt-get update everything works fine, but the window is still popping up. Anybody an idee what`s going wrong?

Comment: I would suggest trying to upgrade using bash/command-line.   Please also note `sudo apt-get update` only updates your repository lists, and does **not** upgrade any software packages. After updating repo.lists, you can `sudo apt-get upgrade` (to upgrade packages with limitations) or `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to upgrade everything.  These command lines will output more information, including errors. I'd suggest to do this, and if you get errors, copy & paste them into your question and we can help you more.

Comment: Yep, dist-upgrade does it. Thanks.